# Вывод имён файлов из нескольких input type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который выводит имя файла из `input[type="file"]` в нужный мне элемент с классом *js-value*, так как данное поле имеет кастомный вид.

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
  var value = $("input[type='file']").val();
  $('.js-value').text(value.replace(/.*\\(.+)/, '$1'));
});
```

Всё отлично работает, но теперь на странице два загрузчика файлов: для аватара и обложки профиля.

Как сделать, чтобы для каждого поля выводилось своё имя файла в нужных мне классах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте каждому `input[type="file"]` атрибут (name, id или дополнительный class) с уникальным значением и, на основе этого значения, выбирайте элемент:

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
    $(`.${this.name}`).text(this.value.replace(/.*\\(.+)/, '$1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

avatar <input type="file" name="avatar"><p class="js-value avatar"></p>
cover <input type="file" name="cover"><p class="js-value cover"></p>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всё работает, как надо.